# Datadog - only alert after X amount of time

Tags: datadog

created new metric monitor, which triggers if threshold > 10 %
But i want it to trigger only if threshold > 10 for more than **30 minutes**

[image]

I cant find such option. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Try set evaluate the average of query over the last 30 mins
[image]

Also try to delay monitor evaluation by 1800 seconds
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set the monitor to evaluate the `min` of the query over the last `30 minutes`.

If the smallest number over 30 minutes is above your threshold, that means the monitor never dipped below that threshold for the entire evaluation window.

Don't put any evaluation delay.